# What XML libraries can I use with Android and Windows?

Tags: java, android, windows

I want to build 2 applications in java for windows and one for Android. I want to use the dame library for XML parsing so i can target to different platforms in the same project. Are there any java XML libraries that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

sax and dom are supported by java & android(which just keep the api in java).

Comment: Thanks. I had no clue if android uses all java's libraries.

Comment: You can unzip an  android.jar file and you'll find packages named org.w3c.dom，org.xml.sax,and so do the rt.jar(java sdk's main lib file).